# How to have margin between table elements?

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I have the margin between two `td` elements?

```css
table {
  border: none;
}

table tr {
  height: 40px;
}

table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 30px;
  width: 400px;
}

table tr td {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Gebäudetyp</td>
    <td>Mall</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Anzahl von Leuchten</td>
    <td>450</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wattage alt</td>
    <td>70 W</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Betriebsstunden</td>
    <td>6.500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Stromverbrauch/Jahr</td>
    <td>290.000 KWh</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Strompreis</td>
    <td>55 Cent/KWh</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Investition</td>
    <td>155.203 Euro</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

if I add `padding-left: 30px` to the second element of `td` it gives padding, but I want to have gap between elements.

Desired output should be:

[image: output]

Comment: [CSS Gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap)

Comment: @albjerto are you sure it can be applied to tables?

Comment: you're right, I was thinking about CSS grids. For tables, you need `border-spacing`

Comment: @albjerto `border-spacing` does not really solve the problem as it adds spacing to all sides. I have changed my `table` into `div` elements and added `flex` and `margin`

Comment: you can simply use CSS pseudo-class selectors like `:nth-child` to only select the second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not required to use `table`, you can do it with `div` and `flex`

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}

.content .left .element,
.content .right .element {
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}

.content .left .element:last-child,
.content .right .element:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.content .left {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.content .right {
  width: 400px;
}

.content .left p,
.content .right p {
  font-size: 19px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
            <div class="left">
              <div class="element">
                <p>Gebäudetyp</p>
              </div>
              <div class="element">
                <p>Anzahl von Leuchten</p>
              </div>
              <div class="element">
                <p>Wattage alt</p>
              </div>
              <div class="element">
                <p>Betriebsstunden</p>
              </div>
              <div class="element">
                <p>Stromverbrauch/Jahr</p>
              </div>
              <div class="element">
                <p>Strompreis</p>
              </div>
              <div class="element">
                <p>Investition</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
              <div class="element">
                <p>Mall</p>
              </div>
              <div class="element">
                <p>450</p>
              </div>
              <div class="element">
                <p>70 W</p>
              </div>
              <div class="element">
                <p>6.500</p>
              </div>
              <div class="element">
                <p>290.000 KWh</p>
              </div>
              <div class="element">
                <p>55 Cent/KWh</p>
              </div>
              <div class="element">
                <p>155.203 Euro</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this CSS rule to move all second cells to the right by 30px, creating empty space between the cells that way:

```
td:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```css
table {
  border: none;
}

table tr {
  height: 40px;
}

table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 400px;
}

table tr td {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  color: #000;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Gebäudetyp</td>
    <td>Mall</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Anzahl von Leuchten</td>
    <td>450</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wattage alt</td>
    <td>70 W</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Betriebsstunden</td>
    <td>6.500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Stromverbrauch/Jahr</td>
    <td>290.000 KWh</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Strompreis</td>
    <td>55 Cent/KWh</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Investition</td>
    <td>155.203 Euro</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the space between `table` cells, use `border-spacing` property on the `table` element,
you can use single value for `border-spacing` propety and it apply to table columns and rows.
ex:

```
table {
  border-spacing: 30px;
}
```

read more about this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_table_padding_spacing.asp)

if you add two values for the `border-spacing` propety, you can have spacing  separately for table column and row.

```
   table {
         border-spacing:Xvalue yValue;
        }
```

`Xvalue` is used for changing table space for columns and `yValue` is used for changing space between rows.

Comment: It's messing up the design, I want to have margin only on the right side of first element like in image.

Answer (score 1):

use `border-spacing` on `table` for spacing and negative margin to get rid of extra space.

```
table {
    border-spacing: 15px 0;
    margin: 0 -15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/874k5a1c/